# Reset iOS App Version Numbering in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

## TLDR; Is there a way to reset the app version of an iOS app in the AppStore?

#### Backstory:

> This is my first time publishing an iOS App and at the start of the development, I got the App version and Build number in reverse (thus the image below). I got away with this by just providing the actual version number in the app store listing but sooner and later, my boss found out about this and now they want me to fix this.

[image]

My options as of this moment are the following:

1. Put down the current App then create a new one where the versioning is correct.

   > Not sure if I can still reuse the current app bundle or must create a new one.
2. Try to convince my boss that we should just slip this through since we can override the displayed app version in the app store listing.

   > I tried to look at the iPhone's `Setting > General > iPhone Storage` and there the incorrect version was.

What's my best options here? If not then what else can I do about this.

Comment: So what version number do you (your boss) finally want to be the current one?

Comment: You can not publish a version lower than a previously released version, so at this point you must publish a version higher than 5.0.4

Comment: @FlorianMielke the current version is 5.0.4 but we want to reset it back to 1.0.4

Comment: @Paulw11 I know about this and I'm looking for workarounds to make it happen, may it be removing the app in the app store then re-release it again, or using a new app bundle then release with the proper versioning convention

Comment: Yes, releasing a new app with a new bundle ID will work.  You may be able to remove the existing app from the App Store, delete it from App Store connect and create a new App, but it may detect that that bundle ID has already been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no "right" or "wrong" versioning. There are only 2 constraints in App Store Connect:

- **Version numbers** (in your case 3, 4, 5, 5.0.4) need to increase. You can't have 5.0.3 after 5.0.4 and so on.
- The second is about **build numbers**. They also need to increase, but get "reseted" for each version. Some people decide to use 1, 2, 3 etc. for the builds, others use the version and then increase (5.0.1.1, 5.0.1.2, 5.0.1.3)

Those version/builds numbers have actually nothing to do with what customers/users see on the App Store. This version number gets managed through App Store Connect and can be completely independent of the version number coming from Xcode.

[image]

I'm also not sure what your boss considers a "wrong" and "right" number. Maybe s/he should have been more precise in the beginning.

As people mentioned in the comments, you cannot reset the versioning. If you setup a brand new app, you can start with the "correct" numbering and implement the logic s/he wants. But you cannot re-use the same bundle ID and people will also not be able to update their existing app.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to create a new app, but there can be problems to name it exactly like the existing one. And of course current users will not get updates for it. If you don't have too many users right know, that is still probably the best solution.